# Attaching an image to a model in a Rails 6 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I've already done my research on this matter but the solutions i've come across seem rather complex to achieve my simple goals.
I'm building an API in which some models should have an image attached. This API returns JSON format and it should also return an image for the frontend to consume.
Is it too bad to just upload the images to let's say a dropbox folder and just paste the image urls into my db objects in an img dedicated field as a string?

Something like:

> rails g model MyModel title:string description:string image_url:string

This is for a project i've been assigned as a task to possibly get a job interview after.
Is this not possible? is it just wrong? Learning how to Base64 encoding seems overkill for my purposes.

Maybe you have encountered this same dilemma before and you can tell me how you solved it and why. Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: It will be easier if you utilize Rails Active Storage to attach files to your models. Active Storage will generate the link to return to the front end.

Comment: I will look into it in the documentation. Thank you.

Comment: "Active Storage uses polymorphic associations via the Attachment join model, which then connects to the actual Blob" ... which is the exact reason you do _not_ want to use Active Storage. Polymorphism is a general red flag in database design as it is hard to implement correct database layer constraints. A better solution would be to upload the image to a storage service, like s3, and serve up the file looking at the location in the front end. Another side thought: this is for the possibility of getting a job interview!? This task is much too involved

Comment: @benjessop I'll bite... what do you mean much too involved? Building the API is a "test". We have like a month to build it, after that, if we succeed, we'll go into a "trainee program" of sorts, AND after that, if we have succeded, we'll probably get an interview. Honestly i'm just doing it for the ride. Thank you for your advice on the image thing, i will look into it.